# Getting token errors whilst trying to connect to the Slack API

Tags: python, slack-api

```
# Set up Slack tokens
slack_bot_token = 'Y'
slack_app_token = 'Z'


# Initialize Slack clients
slack_client = WebClient(token=slack_bot_token)

app = App(token=slack_app_token)


def run_conversation(user_input):
   while True:

        # Step 1: send the conversation and available functions to the model
        messages = [{"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant that interacts with different APIs. You understand when to call an API versus when to respond without calling an API."}, 
                    {"role": "user", "content": user_input}]
        response = client.chat.completions.create(
            model="gpt-3.5-turbo-1106",
            messages=messages,
            tools=tools,
            tool_choice="auto",  # auto is default, but we'll be explicit
        )

        response_message = response.choices[0].message
        tool_calls = response_message.tool_calls
        # Step 2: check if the model wanted to call a function
        if tool_calls:
            # Step 3: call the function
            # Note: the JSON response may not always be valid; be sure to handle errors
            available_tools = {        
                    "create_event": gcal_client.create_event,
                    "update_event": gcal_client.update_event,
                    "delete_event": gcal_client.delete_event,
                    "send_email":  gmail_client.send_email,
            }  
            
            messages.append(response_message)  # extend conversation with assistant's reply
        
            # Step 4: send the info for each function call and function response to the model
            for tool_call in tool_calls:
                tool_name = tool_call.function.name 
                tool_to_call = available_tools[tool_name]
                tool_args = json.loads(tool_call.function.arguments) #
                tool_response = tool_to_call(**tool_args)
                
                # If the tool_response is a tuple, take the first element
                if isinstance(tool_response, tuple):
                    tool_response = tool_response[0]

                # Convert the tool_response to a string if it's a dictionary
                if isinstance(tool_response, dict):
                    tool_response = json.dumps(tool_response)
            
                messages.append(
                    {
                        "tool_call_id": tool_call.id,
                        "role": "tool",
                        "name": tool_name,
                        "content": tool_response,
                    }
                )  
            
            response = client.chat.completions.create(
            model="gpt-3.5-turbo-1106",
            messages=messages)

            return response.choices[0].message.content

        else:
            # Send user input directly to OpenAI API
            '''     response = client.chat.completions.create( 
                model="gpt-3.5-turbo-1106",
                messages=[
                    {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant that interacts with different APIs. You understand when to call an API versus when to respond without calling an API."}, 
                    {"role": "user", "content": user_input}
                ]
            ) '''
            messages.append(response_message)


            # extend conversation with function response
            second_response = client.chat.completions.create(
                model="gpt-3.5-turbo-1106",
                messages=messages,
            )  # get a new response from the model where it can see the functionresponse
            
            return second_response.choices[0].message.content
 
 
# Event listener for incoming messages from Slack
@app.event("message")
def message(event, say, logger):
    text = event["text"]
    print(text)
    user_id = event.get("user")
    print(user_id)
    if user_id is not None and text is not None:
        response = run_conversation(text)  # Pass the message text as user_input
        say(response)  # Sends the response back to the Slack channel

# Event listener for app mentions
@app.event("app_mention")
def handle_app_mention_events(event, say, logger):
    text = event.get("text", "")
    user_id = event.get("user")
    if user_id is not None and text.strip():
        response = run_conversation(text)  # Pass the message text as user_input
        say(response)  # Sends the response back to the Slack channel

# Run the Flask server to listen for incoming Slack events
if __name__ == "__main__":
    SocketModeHandler(app, app_token=slack_app_token).start()
```

When I run the code above (specifically the Slack code), I get the message "Bolt app is running!" in my console. But when I enter a message @Bot "Hey, how are you?" in the relevant channel I get the error:

> Failed to run listener function (error: The request to the Slack API failed. (url: https://www.slack.com/api/chat.postMessage)
> The server responded with: {'ok': False, 'error': 'not_allowed_token_type'})

The bot/app has already been invited to the channel I am sending the message in, the app already has all the relevant permissions (see below) and I have double checked that the app token matches the one on the Slack API settings.

[image]

I am not sure what else I could do to troubleshoot this?

Comment: What are the first 4 letters of your token? The first 4 letters determine what kind of token it is.